# Some resources for beginner-intermediate android learning

Tags: java, android

I am relatively new to Android programming, but not a beginner. I looked into the official documentation Google provides but that sometimes is too complicated for me. And other websites only have snippets or bits and pieces here and there. Can I please be guided towards a one-stop Android learning website or video-series? Like W3schools is for HTML,CSS,PHP etc.

Comment: Hi Jay, for learning everything in a simple way, just try to find Vogella pages for every topic, you want to learn. Vogella explains things in a simpler way.  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Android/article.html

Comment: ok I'll check it out. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check video series on youtube by thenewboston.( type android tutorial on search bar in YouTube)
Author is Travis (He also has up-to-date site as http://www.mybringback.com). I really find it useful as a Well-informed-beginner. It consists of 200 small videos ( 5-10 minutes maximum each).

The series is little old but applies in most of the cases.

Comment: Yes I heard of that. Ok I'll look into it

Answer (score 1):

through these websites you can get good examples as well as more information about android features.hope these sites will make you learn android well.choose anyone of these.here you go.1.androidhive.info
                     2.learnandroideasily.com,3.androidbegin.com

Comment: Thanks for the helpful list. I'll check the links out

Answer (score 0):

Google has a free course on Udacity: https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-android-apps--ud853

Answer (score 0):

Try a video series called "thenewboston". They have great resources on beginner android development! But it uses eclipse but you can easily relate the same to Android studio! Good luck!